# How to make a confirmation after sending sms from emulator to other mobile numbers?

Tags: android, eclipse, sendmessage

Assume,

i have sent a sms from emulator to my mobile number,but my mobile received nothing.Is it possible to view that sent sms on my mobile from "EMULATOR".If so how?

I have done this so far and its toasting as "SMS sent".
Please find my source below

```
public class Send_sms extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "Send_sms";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main12);

    Button sndbtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.but_send_ok);
    sndbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        EditText addrTxt = (EditText)Send_sms.this.findViewById(R.id.editText_number);
        EditText msgTxt = (EditText)Send_sms.this.findViewById(R.id.editText_write_msg);
        try
        {
            sendSmsMessage(addrTxt.getText().toString(),msgTxt.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(Send_sms.this,"Sms sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Send_sms.this,"Failed to send sms",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }});
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}
private void sendSmsMessage(String address,String message)throws Exception
{
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address,null,message,null,null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to send sms for emulator to real device because Emulator has a virtual device and a virtual device not able to communicate with a real device but you are able to send sms from a virtual device to another virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PendingIntent` object you're able to receive notifications from the Android system whether SMS was sent successfully or it failed.

To do so the 4th and 5th parameter of `sendTextMessage()` should be set. See details here: [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

For a working example check this out: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android